# Url to raw github csv keeps changing when I try to download to google colab

Tags: python, pandas, csv, github, google-colaboratory

I am trying to download a large .csv file from where I have it stored in my github to a notebook I have in google colab. Here is the scheme of the code I am using:

```py
#download fixed data sets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url_train = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/data/master/train_fixed.csv?token=[long_string]'
x_train = pd.read_csv(url_train)
```

Usually this will work fun. Frequently, however, (but not always) if I close the notebook and re-open a day later, if I just re-run the code I get a 404 not found error for the URL, and have to go back to github and recopy the (now changed) raw URL for my file.

I am not sure why this is happening or what I was sure, and I wanted to ask if anyone else has experienced this problem and what solutions you would recommend. Perhaps the problem is because this repo is private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the repo is private, it's likely that the `token` argument expires so that accidental disclosure of the URL does not prevent access to the data without possibility of revocation. My recommendation is to arrange to construct the URL dynamically after fetching the `token` parameter in the context of your current session.

Comment: Thank you! How might I arrange to construct the URL dynamically after fetching the token parameter in the context of my current session?

Comment: How are you retrieving the URL now?

Comment: I go to the my github, then to the data folder, then I clcik on the file "train_fixed," then I click view raw and copy and paste the url into my colab (url_train = '[copy and paste]'

Comment: Ah, you'll need to switch to using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to retrieve the data programmatically.